# Равнина вся была как разлинованное узкими полосками рисовое поле

Tags: синтаксис

Нужна ли запятая перед "как"?
Равнина вся была как разлинованное узкими полосками рисовое поле.
На мой взгляд не нужна, т. к. "как" входит в составное глагольное сказуемое.
Прав ли я?

Comment: Вы уверены, что иенно в **глагольное**?

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна, оборот входит в состав составного именного сказуемого: Равнина вся **была как  поле**. Оборот является именной частью.